# Using a COTS common mode choke on DC

Tags: saturation, derating, common-mode-choke

Are commercially available common-mode chokes, such as one you'd pull out of a dead switching supply, suitable for DC service up to their rated current, or will they saturate/do other baleful things when subject to their rated current as DC instead of mains frequency AC?  Do they need to be derated at all for DC service?

Comment: The steady state for an inductor in DC is short circuit and fully deenergized.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- for that mythical ideal inductor, yes ;) but real CMCs are powdered-iron or ferrite core beasts with all sorts of quirks and nonidealities, and I wanted to sanity-check that I wasn't going to get bit on the rear by one if I just blindly grabbed/ordered a COTS part that's likely made for AC mains service.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you use them common mode they will be fine, but if the current becomes unbalanced they will quickly saturate and become less effective.